# Untracked files: после commit'a папка уже есть в гите и у меня локально

Tags: git, git-commit

После очередного коммита я изменил один файл, и попытался сделать еще один коммит...

И вижу такую картину, что папка и все файлы внутри нее отображены как новые в секции `untracked files`.
Эта папка с файлами уже очень давно в есть в гите и у меня локально. В ней я изменил только файл (измененил пару строк внутри файла).
Порядок выполнения моих действий практически всегда такой:

```
git status
git add --all
git status
git commit -m "bla bla bla"
git pull origin master
// устраняю конфликты если они есть и повторяю git add, commit
git push origin master
```

При последнем коммите не было никаких конфликтов или каких либо странных или необычных поведений git..
Но почему папка со всеми ее файлами которая была под контролем вдруг оказалась как новая, понять не могу и главное как исправить не нарушит ли это работу?

Comment: Что показывает `git diff --name-status HEAD^`? Может, вы случайно сделали `git rm --cached <имя-папки>`?

Comment: `git fsck`? И кстати, `git commit -a -s -m "..."` убивает сразу пару зайцев